# Fukushima, Japan restricted areas?

Tags: japan, safety

I am interested in learning about the current status of the restricted zone surrounding the Fukushima nuclear power plant, which experienced a nuclear incident in 2011. A [specific map](https://www.meti.go.jp/english/earthquake/nuclear/roadmap/pdf/20210518_02.pdf) on a website depicts the area in question. I am curious to know if the area shaded in grey represents the restricted zone.

By "restricted zone," does it imply that residency is prohibited, but visits are allowed? From my observation on Google Maps, it appears that there are operational businesses, including restaurants, within this zone. Additionally, railway stations such as Namie are also in service.

So, what exactly are the restrictions within this zone? Can tourists or visitors explore these places freely, as long as they do not trespass on private property?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, the grey area is the restricted area: you can travel through it by car along specific routes, but are not supposed to stop or get out of your car.

However, the blue-grey zones on the map are *former* restricted areas that are now open to the public, and this includes the train stations of Namie and Futaba as well as the nearby urban centers.  This [Japanese version of the map](https://www.meti.go.jp/earthquake/nuclear/kinkyu/hinanshiji/2023/rbetto5_map.jpg) makes the current boundaries are little clearer.

Comment: Is there also a map of what the actual radiation levels are in each zone?

Comment: @JonathanReez-onstrike Here's one for all Japan: https://jciv.iidj.net/map/